# How do I reset all global variables?

Tags: swift, global-variables, logout

I want to reset all my global variables when a user logs out as otherwise some of their information will stay (the info in global variables).

Is there any way to do this without manually resetting them to their initial value when the log out button is pressed?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you are saving the user-data into a global variable? That doesn't seem to make sense for me.

If you are intending to equal **NSUserDefaults** as **global variables**, you can use the following approach to delete the Data from your standard UserDefaults:

```
private func cleanUserDefaultsOnLogout() {
    let standardDefaults = UserDefaults.standard
    for key in standardDefaults.dictionaryRepresentation().keys {
        standardDefaults.removeObject(forKey: key)
    }
    standardDefaults.synchronize()
}
```

Please correct me if I've misinterpreted your question.

Comment: Yeah I'd think to use NSUserDefaults but the problem is that I need them to be accessible across different screens so that's why I've put them as global variables. So for example I have a mealsArray which goes into Tab1 - Rota, Tab2 - List of Meals and Tab 3 - Ingredients from the mealsArray. If they were local and NSUserDefaults then they wouldn't be accessible. Or am I misinterpreting this?

Comment: NSUserDefaults are accessible over different ViewControllers, just instatiate a new object of 'UserDefaults.standard' and access them via their key.

Comment: I did not know that, only a couple of months into swift. Thank you so much, very useful @cr0ss

Answer (score 0):

```
extension UserDefaults {
    class func clean() {
        guard let aValidIdentifier = 
Bundle.main.bundleIdentifier else { return }
        self.standard.removePersistentDomain(forName: 
aValidIdentifier)
        self.standard.synchronize()
    }
}   

use it 
UserDefaults.clean()
```

Comment: add relevant explanation to or answer